# How to see if a Class<?> is actually Class<T>?

Tags: java, casting, classcastexception

I have a generic method, which should look up a class of a specific type. I manage to get that class as a `Class<?>`, now I want to check if it really is of the requested type, and if so, return it (otherwise null). The only code that seemed to work is to just try the cast, and throw an exception if it failed. I am worried about the performance of that code though, since it will be used very often and I heard that throwing exceptions is not very performant.

```
public static <T> Class<T> getThatClass() {
    Class<?> clazz = // some internal lookup
    try {
        return (Class<T>) clazz;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to check if `clazz` is of type `E` without exceptions? I would want something like this, but sadly, that does not compile:

```
public static <T> Class<T> getThatClass2() {
    Class<?> clazz = // some internal lookup
    if (clazz instanceof Class<T>) {
        return (Class<T>) clazz;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Class` has an `asSubclass` method, which will throw a `ClassCastException` if not.  Although for that to be viable, you'd need to pass `Class<T>` from somewhere however (method signature, constructor to utility class, etc.) - in your example there would be no way for the runtime to determine what `T.class` would be (and the compiler will complain accordingly).

Comment: "I am worried about the performance of that code though, since it will be used very often". If you're using that code very often, I'm more worried about what on earth you're doing, than about the performance of that code.

Comment: This feels quite a lot like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).  Why do you need this?  You can always cast the result of reflectively invoked methods or constructors.

Answer (score 2):

`Class.isAssignableFrom(..)` is the non-instance variant for type checking. Usage:

```
Assert.assertTrue(Number.class.isAssignableFrom(Integer.class));
Assert.assertTrue(Number.class.isAssignableFrom(Double.class));
Assert.assertFalse(Number.class.isAssignableFrom(String.class));

Collection<Integer> c = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
Assert.assertTrue(List.class.isAssignableFrom(c.getClass()));
Assert.assertFalse(Set.class.isAssignableFrom(c.getClass()));
```

It also contains useful methods for instanceof checks and casting:

```
Assert.assertTrue(List.class.isInstance(c));
List<Integer> list = List.class.cast(c);
```

Comment: ...and then the method would have to be `public static <T> Class<T> getThatClass(Class<T> clazz)`, so it can be tested against (since you can get `clazz.class`, but not `T.class`).

Answer (score 0):

Java Generics don't exist at Runtime. Generics is strictly a compile-time safety feature. What you could do is something like

```
public static Class<?> getThatClass2(String nameToMatch) {
  Class<?> clazz = // some internal lookup
  if (clazz.getName().equals(nameToMatch) {
    return clazz;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

I did not copy/paste this from somewhere else on SO. If I had found a duplicate, I would have voted closed - duplicate